# Javascript - copy link

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to extract a part of a website address and append it to an other link.

Example: website.com/abc123 --> otherwebsite.com/abc123

Is there an easy way to do this?
I'm new to JavaScript

Comment: Please provide more details

Comment: What details do you need?

Comment: Do you want your code to run in a browser or somewhere else? If browser, do you want to read the current window URL, or apply the transformation for any potential URLs? Finally, is the transformation about copying the path part from one URL and appending it to another domain? Or are there different transformations?

Comment: You got 3 answers to the question by now. Is one among them that solves your problem? If yes, would you mind accepting / voting? http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function returnNewAdress(adr, ows) {
    return ows + adr.substring(adr.indexOf("/"), adr.length);
}

returnNewAdress("website.com/abc123", "otherwebsite.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function OtherURL(What) {
  NewURL='otherwebsite.com';
  return NewURL+'\/'+What.substring(What.lastIndexOf('\/'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear in what environment the function should run.
In node.js you could do this:

```
var transformUrl = function (url, newDomain) { 
    if (! url.match(/https?:\/\//i)) {
        // prepend URL with protocol if missing 
        url = "http://" + url; 
    } 
    return newDomain + require("url").parse(url).path; 
};

// can be called like this:
// this will return 'otherwebsite.com/abc123'
transformUrl("website.com/abc123", "otherwebsite.com");
transformUrl("http://website.com/abc123", "otherwebsite.com");
```